# Selectively sync Outlook mail subfolders with mobile device

Tags: windows-7, sync, microsoft-outlook-2010

In ActiveSync and Windows XP, I could select which Outlook 2010 sections and mail subfolders I wanted to synchronize with my HTC phone. I can't find a similar option in Windows 7 Sync Center.

My Outlook.pst file is 800 MB heavy, and Sync Center won't synchronize that much data. It says I have to remove some items, which I don't want to do.

Is there a way to selectively configure what's to be sync'd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I was looking in the wrong program; when I connect my smartphone "Sync Center" start up from the Control Panel, but you don't want that to manage your partnership.

The "Mobile Device Center" (under Start | Programs) gives me the settings I also had in ActiveSync:

[image]